# Is there any way to unzip the file in linux without being through the "unzip" command?

Tags: linux, shell, zip

Is there any way to unzip the file in Linux without being through the `unzip` command?

We can not install the software `unzip` or any decompressor for now and need to unpack some files in a script that was created.

I used the `jar -xf file.zip` command in a ZIP file with several files inside, however only the first file was extracted and the error below was presented in the terminal, any idea what it might be?

```
java.io.IOException: Push back buffer is full
        at java.io.PushbackInputStream.unread(PushbackInputStream.java:215)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:367)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:156)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:100)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.extractFile(Main.java:936)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.extract(Main.java:852)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:242)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1149)
```

When I ran the `jar tvf file.zip` command, I was able to see everything inside `file.zip`.

Comment: Looks like you may have a corrupt zip file.

Comment: You may have 7z, or in you have a Graphical UI, it may have an archive decompressor (`ark` in KDE) or the navigator can natively handle ZIP files as diectories (`dolphin` in KDE).

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot install the necessary software on the target machine, consider moving the ZIP file to a machine that already has the necessary software. (ZIP extractors available not only on Linux machines but Windows and Mac too.)

Then either repack the files using a compatible compressor or copy the extracted bundle back again. There are file transfer tools available for just about any platform you can name.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the jar file may be corrupt in some regard.

To get `unzip` made available on the server, install unzip package on another server, and then scp the `/usr/bin/unzip` to `/tmp/myunzip` on your troubled server, and then just use that binary.